# Patterns for role-based behaviour

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm involved in an application migration project. This application is supposed to execute some logic based on the current user role, so this snippets like this are everywhere in the code:

```
if ("Role1".equals(user.getUserRole())){
    operationVersionForRole1();
} else if ("Role2".equals(user.getRole())){
    operationVersionForRole2();  
} else if ("Role3".equals(user.getRole())){
    operationVersionForRole3();
}
```

There are about five roles and almost fifty operations, and some operations are very complex for some roles (almost 1000 lines of code) so that style of programming makes the source code messy and hard to follow. Is there any know design pattern that helps to organize source code in that situations? Nested "if-else" just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it a *Abstract Factory* that provides an interface for creating  families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete class? Specified role will be an argument to create concrete implementation. And `operationVersionForRoleX` could be designed as different implementation or strategy of `IOperation` interface.

```
interface IOperation  
{ 
    void Execute();
}

class OperationVersionForRoleX : IOperation
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // …
    }
}

string role = "roleX";
IOperation operation = operationFactory.Create(role);
operation.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simmilar to what casablanca has answered.

- I usually avoid business logic inside an enum since their job is just uniqueness and pretty much are inferior to classes in everything else.

  public enum Role {

  ```
  ROLE1 { public Actions getActions(){ return new Role1Actions() } },
  ROLE2 { public Actions getActions(){ return new Role2Actions() } },
  ROLE3 { public Actions getActions(){ return new Role3Actions() } };
  ```

  }
- I would make the Actions interface with as many method as types of operations can be executed per role

public interface Actions {

```
void action1();
// useful when there are more than 1 different actions per role
// even if only 1 now, there will be more in the future
vpod action2();
}
```

- Then, just use the actions you can get from roles

  user.getUserRole().action1();

  user.getUserRole().action2();

Comment: That implies that all operation logic per Role would be in only one class. Some operations are pretty complex (almost 1000 lines of code). Wouldn't that produce Blobs and violate SRP?

Comment: Not one class, one interface. The implementing classES can be agregates of even more classes. In a nutshell, it's a kind of Strategy Design Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where all operations extend the `Operation` superclass and `Role` is an actual object instead of a string:

```
public abstract class Operation {
  public void execute(User user) {
    user.getRole().apply(this);
  }

  public abstract void operationForRole1();
  public abstract void operationForRole2();
  public abstract void operationForRole3();
}

public enum Role {
  ROLE1 { public void apply(Operation op) { op.operationForRole1(); } },
  ROLE2 { public void apply(Operation op) { op.operationForRole2(); } },
  ROLE3 { public void apply(Operation op) { op.operationForRole3(); } };

  public abstract void apply(Operation op);
}
```

Each `Operation` then implements the logic for various roles, and the client simply calls `operation.execute(user)`. No `if-else` anywhere.